# PHP - Desventaja al usar la extension de mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Buenas, necesito ayuda para extraer los datos del usuario logeado en mi sistema.
Esta es mi base de datos con sus respectivos campos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero hacer es que al ingresar el usuario, su email se visible en todas las siguientes paginas. Intente con este codigo:

```
if($rows==1){
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['email']=$rows['email'];
```

Y luego colocar el **$_SESSION['email']** en todas las paginas, pero no pasa nada. Así que agradecería cualquier recomendación.

Este es todo el código que estoy utilizando:

**db.php**

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '123');
if (!$connection){
    die("Database Connection Failed" . mysql_error());
}
$select_db = mysql_select_db('login');
if (!$select_db){
    die("Database Selection Failed" . mysql_error());
}
?>
```

**login.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<?php
    require('db.php');
    session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION["username"])){
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit(); }


    // If form submitted, insert values into the database.
    if (isset($_POST['username'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $username = stripslashes($username);
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
        $password = stripslashes($password);
        $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
    //Checking is user existing in the database or not
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='$username' and password='".md5($password)."'";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if($rows==1){
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            header("Location: index.php"); // Redirect user to index.php
            }else{
                echo "<div class='form'><h3>Username/password is incorrect.</h3><br/>Click here to <a href='login.php'>Login</a></div>";
                }
    }else{
?>
<div class="form">
<h1>Log In</h1>
<form action="" method="post" name="login">
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required />
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
<p>Not registered yet? <a href='registration.php'>Register Here</a></p>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**auth.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])){
header("Location: login.php");
exit(); }
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php include("auth.php"); //include auth.php file on all secure pages ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Welcome Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="form">
<p>Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>!</p>
<p>This is secure area.</p>
<p><a href="dashboard.php">Dashboard</a></p>
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

*** Por ultimo, me dijeron que el codigo que estoy usando esta obsoleto (mysql) y que usara el mysqli... mi dudad es:

**¿Qué problemas me ocasionara usar código obsoleto?**

Este es un pequeño trabajo, mientras intento aprender php, porque hasta el momento estoy nulo en este lenguaje.

Comment: te recomiendo que uses PDO o MySQLI.

Comment: no uses mysqli tampoco usa PDO checa esta app que hize usando PDO https://github.com/rojobo/PHP7MessageBoard

Comment: El problema es que el código obsoleto puede no estar presente en la próxima versión de php, con lo cual, todo tu sistema podría dejar de funcionar si actualizas tu sistema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cordial Saludo,

1. Cambia tu codigo

   > $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
   >   
   >          if($rows==1){
   >   
   >             $_SESSION['email']=$rows['email'];

por

> $count_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
>   
>          if($count_rows ==1){
>   
> while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
>   
>  $_SESSION['email'] = $row["email"];
>   
> }

tu error es que la funcion **mysql_num_rows** no extrae la informacion de la consulta, para esto se debe usar **mysql_fetch_array**

2. Sobre si usar o no código obsoleto; no es malo para aprender, pero es mejor aprender sobre lo nuevo. Para generar un producto no debes usar las cosas obsoletas

Answer (score 2):

Aqui esta una respuesta a tu pregunta acerca de el codigo obsoleto...

Si usas codigo obsoleto lo mas probable es que en un futuro cuando exista una nueva version de el lenguage tu cudigo ya no funcione para la nueva verison por lo tanto debes de cambiar todo lo obsoleto por el equivalente a algo que sea valido, por lo tanto si usas codigo obsoleto te sera muy dificil mantener tu app al dia con los beneficios que el usar la velocidad y seguridad que las actualizaciones del lenguage traen.

Answer (score 1):

Pues mirá la documentación de PHP comenta lo siguiente:

**¿Por qué el uso de la extensión MySQL (ext/mysql), que he utilizado durante más de 10 años, está desaconsejado? ¿Está obsoleta? ¿Qué utilizo en su lugar? ¿Cómo puedo migrar?**

Existen tres extensiones de MySQL, como está descrito en la sección [Elegir una API de MySQL](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php). No se debe usar la API antigua, está obsoletea a partir de PHP 5.5.0 y ha sido movida a PECL a paritr de PHP 7.0.0. Se recomienda encarecidamente escribir todo el código nuevo con [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php) o [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/es/ref.pdo-mysql.php).

La migración de los scripts no está disponible por el momento, aunque la API mysqli API contiene tanto una API procedimental como una API POO, siendo la versión procedimental similar a ext/mysql.

No es posible mezclar extensiones. Así, por ejemplo, pasar una conexión mysqli a PDO_MySQL o ext/mysql no funcionará.

[Documento Original - FAQ PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated)